# Как вынести сайт на отдельный url (например: /blog) через nginx?

Tags: nginx

Стоит сервер nginx 1.4.6. Есть хост domain.do на котором находится основной сайт. Сейчас стоит задача вынести на отдельный (domain.do/blog) блог на wordpress. Как сделать правльно настройку чтобы все запросы по этому урлу перенаправлялись на вордпресс?